# Combined matches, single value and across multiple columns

Tags: python, dataframe, multiple-columns

DF1 (1000's of products most profitable months)

```
+------+--------+
| YEAR | MONTH  |
+------+--------+
| 1999 | APR    |
+------+--------+
| 2014 | NOV    |
+------+--------+
| 2013 | DEC    |
+------+--------+
| 2017 | FEB    |
+------+--------+
```

DF2 (most profitable months, order is random example. )

```
+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| YEAR | MONTH1 | MONTH2 | MONTH3 | MONTH4 | MONTH5 |
+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 1998 | JAN    | FEB    | SEP    | OCT    | NOV    |
+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 2014 | MAR    | APR    | SEP    | NOV    | DEC    |
+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 2012 | FEB    | MAR    | OCT    | NOV    | DEC    |
+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 2013 | FEB    | APR    | MAY    | JUN    | DEC    |
+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

I need to match `DF1['Year']` to `DF2['YEAR']` and then `DF1['MONTH']` to any values in `DF2` `MONTH1` through `MONTH5` and return a count. I've been able to figure out matching each individually without a problem, but combined is the issue. No need for any values from `DF2` not matching `DF2` `MONTH`

Matching the value from each column (a calendar/date solution will not be very helpful) is important as the next question is similar to dealing with salespeople names and sales years.

Expected output would be

```
+------+--------+
| YEAR | MONTH  |
+------+--------+
| 1999 | APR    |
+------+--------+
| 2014 | NOV    |
+------+--------+
| 2013 | DEC    |
+------+--------+
| 2017 | FEB    |
+------+--------+
```

Coming from a sql/viz background and diving into python; an exciting headche ;) much thanks and sorry for the formatting.

Comment: I cannot understand the df1 and expected output is the same?

Comment: Do you need to know which of the columns the match is in, or just that one of the five columns contains the month from df1?

Comment: @Lamanus DF1 and expected are not the same.

Comment: @josephjscheidt - need to know which column the match is in (as i assume this would be the easiest way to get counts).

Answer (score 0):

So the best way to deal with a dataframe such as df2, where there is a variable of interest present in the columns, (i.e. Month1 through Month5) is to use the pandas melt function to reshape the dataframe into a long format. You can specify the id columns (the columns to leave the same) or the value columns, whichever is easier. Here, you could use something like

```
df2_long = pd.melt(df2, 
                  value_vars = ['MONTH1', 'MONTH2', 'MONTH3', 'MONTH4', 'MONTH5'],
                  var_name = 'MONTH_NUMBER'
                  value_name = 'MONTH')
```

which will leave you with a dataframe that looks like

```
YEAR | MONTH_NUMBER | MONTH
1998 | MONTH_1      | JAN
1998 | MONTH_2      | FEB
1998 | MONTH_3      | SEP
1998 | MONTH_4      | OCT
1998 | MONTH_5      | NOV
2014 | MONTH_1      | MAR
```

etc.

You can then merge them, matching df1 year and month to df2 year and month, and get value counts for month numbers, like so:

```
matches = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'inner', on = ['YEAR', 'MONTH'])

matches['MONTH_NUMBER'].value_counts()
```